# How can i make custom Input Manager in Unity for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a Pong game in unity and I wanted to port it to Android but the problem is I don't realy know how to make it work on mobile. The idea was to just tap on the side of the screen for the paddle to move but Unity Input Manager Doesn't really support things like that and I heard about custom Input Managers but all the tutorials just can't help so I need to ask you.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB9q0.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for touches, get the touch and update the transform of whatever object you're touching(hopefully).

Documentation of concern:

[Touch](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch.html)

[Touch.phase](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html)

[Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)

[Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
 {
     Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); // get first touch since touch count is greater than zero
     
     if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
     {
         // get the touch position from the screen touch to world point
         Vector3 touchedPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 10));
         // lerp and set the position of the current object to that of the touch, but smoothly over time.
         transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, touchedPos, Time.deltaTime);
     }
 }
```